# All my divs expand as I enter text into a single div

Tags: html, css

How do I make my divs not expand as a whole as I enter text on my right div. I'm just trying to make my right div scroll for overflow while the size of all the other divs are the same.

https://codepen.io/waka919/pen/YzwPOgw

```
<div class="grid-container">
<div class=Chart>

</div>
<div class="Data"></div>
<div class=News>
  <h3> Text line 1 </h3>
  <br>
  <h3> Text line 2 </h3>
  <br>
  <h3> Text line 3 </h3>
  <br>
  <h3> Text line 4 </h3>
  <br>
  <h3> Text line 5 </h3>
  <br>
  <h3> Text line 6 </h3>
  <br>
  <h3> Text line 7 </h3>
  <br>
  <h3> Text line 8 </h3>
  <br>
  <h3> Text line 4 </h3>
  <br>
  <h3> Text line 5 </h3>
  <br>
  <h3> Text line 6 </h3>
  <br>
  <h3> Text line 7 </h3>
  <br>
  <h3> Text line 8 </h3>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is because the div's on the left share the height of the outer container, and the container grows bigger due to the extra content inside the div on the right

Comment: to stop this from happening, either set a fixed height to the div's on the left or add `overflow: auto` and  a fixed `height` to add a scrollbar on the right div, so when it grows too big you can scroll

Comment: Thanks, I just gave a my right div a fixed pixel height and it worked.